# Is it possible to share file with one using NFC and another using bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

May I know if it is possible to transfer file from one phone using NFC to another phone using blue-tooth?

I know it is possible to transfer file from one NFC to another NFC. Also, it is possible to transfer file from one blue-tooth to another blue-tooth.

Comment: So you want to get on a plane and arrive in a car?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you have one phone with NFC but no Bluetooth, and another phone with no NFC but Bluetooth, and you want to send a file from one to the other.

That can't work. NFC and Bluetooth are completely unrelated, they can't communicate together. If you want the two devices to communicate, they need to both use Bluetooth, or both use NFC, or both use Wi-Fi. It's as simple as that.